# How can I get Blender to render the 3D view instead of the what's in the VSE?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I added a video sequencer/preview as reference for the animation I am doing, but now when I render, it renders from the sequencer rather than my 3D camera.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In the *Properties panel > Output > Post Processing*, disable the *Sequencer* option.